# Fold / unfold keymap for IdeaVim in Android Studio

Tags: android, ideavim

In VIM, I have the space bar mapped with the fold/unfold command when not in insert mode.

If it is possible, how can I replicate that in Android Studio with the IdeaVim plugin ?

Comment: can you show me your ideavimrc,i want to map <space> to fold/unfold code too.thanks

Comment: @smileVann: nmap <SPACE> za; of course you must first set foldmethod=[whatever method you want (syntax, marker, etc)]

Comment: Would you kind to share  your ideavimrc file?I'm a android developer too and i think i can get a lot from it.Thanks!!!

Comment: @smileVann: if you want examples of ideavimrc files, your best bet is to do a search in github for ideamvirc and/or vimrc files. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `source ~/.vimrc` in your `~/.ideavimrc` to source your vim settings.  Or just copy over the mappings you care about.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, just copy your **_vimrc** file from your Vim  into your $HOME path (usually it is C:/Users/**USER_NAME**/) and rename it to **.ideavimrc**. Then restart Android Studio, and you can get all your keymap setting back.